# Simplest way to "forward" script arguments to another command

Tags: bash

I have following script

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec my_container ./bin/cli
```

And I have to append all arguments passed to the script to the command inside script. So for example executing

```
./script some_command -t --option a
```

Should run

```
docker exec my_container ./bin/cli some_command -t --option a
```

Inside the script. I am looking for simplest/most elegant way.

Comment: Note: if this is all your script does, consider using an `alias` or a bash function rather than a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$@" represent all arguments and support quoted arguments too:

```
docker exec my_container ./bin/cli "$@"
```